# exit vwait loop after client conection

Tags: sockets, tcl

I am trying to use this example from TCL wiki of server script:

```
    # Initialise the state
after 5000 set state timeout
set server [socket -server accept 12345]
proc accept {args} {
    global state connectionInfo
    set state accepted
    set connectionInfo $args
}

# Wait for something to happen
vwait state

# Clean up events that could have happened
close $server
after cancel set state timeout

# Do something based on how the vwait finished...
switch $state {
    timeout {
        puts "no connection on port 12345"
    }
    accepted {
       puts "connection: $connectionInfo"
       puts [lindex $connectionInfo 0] "Hello there!"
    }
}
```

I want that after the clinet open a socket with the server one time then vwait loop will finish and continue run,in case it's fail I will have a timeout.so far so good.
The problem began when for some reason and I get an error with $state and cant run it as a function with a script.
the error I get is: can't read "state": no such variable.altough running its as not a function works properly and I cant understand why.
can anyone help me to fix this issue please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works, *but only if it is evaluated in the global context*; I guess you're trying to run it inside a procedure. What's happening is that the `switch` invocation looks for a local variable `state` instead of a global variable `state`, and doesn't find it, whereas `vwait` always works with global variables and `after` callbacks are evaluated in the global scope.

The fix is to replace

```
switch $state {
```

with

```
switch $::state {
```

Assuming you're happy with using that variable for nothing else.